# Nginx: Cache HIT’s not happening

Tags: nginx

I have a page in **nginx** as follows

```
location = /page {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:82;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status
    proxy_cache             page;
    proxy_cache_key         backend$request_uri;
    proxy_cache_valid       200 302 100d;
    proxy_cache_valid       404      1m;
    proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header;
}
```

With the cache setting as follows

```
proxy_cache_path  /tmp/nginx/cache  levels=1:2 keys_zone=page:10m inactive=7d  max_size=50m;
```

But this page always returns a miss

[image]

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your backend responses have a Set-Cookie header, you need [proxy_ignore_headers](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ignore_headers) Set-Cookie; instead of proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote?  OP has proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie, so it wouldn't appear in the response headers sent back to the client even if the upstream sets it, but afaict, unless you tell nginx to actually *ignore* the header, it will still mark the response as not cacheable.

Comment: It didnt fix the problem..

Comment: Is there anything in the error log?  You could also try telling nginx to ignore Cache-Control, but it should be handling that properly.

Comment: This answer actually works and is also found on Nginx forum. More here: http://serverfault.com/a/736920/297653