# Nginx not caching data

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache, solr

I have a REST API behind an nginx proxy. Proxying works fine, however I am unable to cache any responses. Any help would be much appreciated:

Nginx config:

```
worker_processes  10;
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
        proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache/dir keys_zone=one:60m;
        proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;

     upstream backend {
        server server1 backup;
        server server2 weight=5;
    }
    access_log  logs/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       7076;
        server_name  localhost;
        #charset koi8-r;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

            proxy_cache one;
            proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I have tried, the Proxy-Cache always comes back as a MISS:

Request Headers are:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:nginxserver:portnumber
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
```

Reponse Headers are:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 15 Oct 2014 16:30:18 GMT
Server:nginx/1.7.4
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Proxy-Cache:MISS
```

My suspicion is that it's something with the client headers, but even if I issue the call via curl and check out the headers, there is no response.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the request header: `Cache-Control:max-age=0` ...that implies "don't cache this request."

Comment: Is there a way for me to ignore that in the client header? This doesn't explain why it doesn't work through curl either though....

Comment: @user2630270 What's the initial request URL & method ? What's the intermediate response ?

Comment: @XavierLucas the methods for the headers above are GET since I am now troubleshooting the issue Chrome. The request is something along the lines of http://nginxserver:port/solr/asd/select?q=*:*. I don't know how to capture intermediate response. Where can I find instructions on this?

Comment: If I hit the application directly without going through nginx, with the exactly same query I get the following response headers: 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: @NathanC By default nginx ignore cache-control headers in requests.

Comment: That is what I read as well, but can't confirm. Keep in mind that I am not able to get anything to cache, 0, zip, nada. I think it's an underlying problem with my config. Can you guys give it a second look? First time nginx user....

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You didn't tell NGINX for how much time the response is valid and must be served from cache.

This must be specified with [`proxy_cache_valid`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid) directive.

```
proxy_cache one;
proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
```

But, this won't work for POST requests because you have no cache key that differs from a POST request to another on the same URL if they don't have same content.

So you will need to adjust the cache key to `$host$request_uri|$request_body`. You will have to monitor the cache size (`proxy_cache_path` parameter `max_size`) and proxy response buffer `proxy_buffer_size`  so it suits your needs.

Comment: Nice, Thanks man! It worked. Wish it was documented somewhere a bit more explicitly.

Comment: If this directive is not set then any response will be cached. But the one is overriden by the header X-Accel-Expire, Cache-Control or Expire of the app. At least, Set-Cookie and Vary could avoid the cache. These facts are exposed in the doc. I created a simple script to test because my framework, Laravel, always send the above headers.

Comment: This worked Xiavier Lucas. Thanks.  I also added a difference cache time value for different HTTP codes :  proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m; //////  proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;

Comment: This is it. How would we find this out from documentation? Good question. Maybe by looking at what options have no default (`Default:  —`), which would suggest they need configuring before anything useful happens...

Answer (score 17):

From: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid

> Syntax:    proxy_cache_valid [code ...] time;
>
> ...
>
> Parameters of caching can also be set directly in the response header.
>   This has **higher priority** than setting of caching time using the
>   directive.
>
> - The “X-Accel-Expires” header field sets caching time of a response in    seconds. The zero value disables caching for a response. If the
>     value    starts with the @ prefix, it sets an absolute time in seconds
>     since    Epoch, up to which the response may be cached.
> - If the header does not include the “X-Accel-Expires” field,    parameters of caching may be set in the header fields “Expires” or
>     “Cache-Control”.
> - If the header includes the **“Set-Cookie”** field, such a response will    not be cached.
> - If the header includes the “Vary” field with the special value “*”,    such a response will not be cached (1.7.7). If the header includes
>     the “Vary” field with another value, such a response will be cached
>     taking into account the corresponding request header fields (1.7.7).
>
> Processing of one or more of these response header fields can be
>   disabled using the **proxy_ignore_headers** directive.

Most web apps set `Set-Cookie` header, so a response will not be cached. To fix that, use this directive:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
```